# Jupyter Notebook の sys.stdout を io.TextIOWrapper でラップできない

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
import sys, io

# UTF8にエンコード
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout, encoding='utf-8')

print("hello")
```

上記のコードを実行したところ、

```
UnsupportedOperation                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-7af1dd44dff7> in <module>()
     21     s.decompose()
     22 text = ' '.join(soup.stripped_strings)
---> 23 print(text)

UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

というエラーが出てしまいました。原因が不明のため、ご教授お願いします。jupyternotebookで実行しています。

Answer (score 2):

jupyter notebookを使用している場合、出力先はipythonになります。

```
import sys, io
sys.stdout
```

上のコードを実行すると

```
<ipykernel.iostream.OutStream at 0xXXXXXXXXXXXX>
```

というようになります。

jupyter notebookへの出力でコード変換をするとすれば、下のようなコードになると思うのですが

```
sys.stdout = ipykernel.iostream.OutStream(encoding='utf-8')
```

以下のようなエラーになってしまいます。

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-90d17bbb039b> in <module>()
----> 1 sys.stdout = ipykernel.iostream.OutStream(encoding='utf-8')

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'
```

最近は、UTF-8固定の時代になってきているので、UTF8にエンコードすることは忘れてもいいのではないでしょうか。